# [NSImage setHidden:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsimage

macOS Xcode Objective-C. Very new, so bear with me.

Displaying an image programmatically using:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        m_imgBack = nil;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    rect = [ self bounds ];
    if( m_imgBack )
      [m_imgBack drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,rect.size.width,rect.size.height) fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
}

- (void)InitControls {
    LoadImageFromFile( [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/common/background.png", DATA_PATHNAME ], &m_imgBack );
}
```

This draws the background.png without a problem. However, I can not see to hide it using:

```
[m_imgBack setHidden:YES];
```

It just kicks back error: [NSImage setHidden:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. I thought you could sethidden on an NSImage?

Comment: You want to hide a `NSImageView` (which implements as NSView `setHidden:`), not a `NSImage`, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of `NSImage` as a data object, so hiding it doesn't make sense just like hiding an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` doesn't make sense.

If you're displaying the image in a view, the view can be hidden using [isHidden](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483369-ishidden). It's not clear from the code snippet what class the code belongs to, but assuming it's a subclass of `NSView`, you could try `[self setHidden:YES]`.

Comment: Thank you - I was thinking you could put images on an NSView and then hide the images. The proper way is to hide an NSView/NSImageView and not the actual image.